# nodemon not working on basic script

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I have a directory "test" with "test.js" inside. The script contents are simply:

```
console.log('testing!');
```

After navigating to the folder I run:

```
$ nodemon test.js

11 Oct 16:33:42 - [nodemon] 1.7.1
11 Oct 16:33:42 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
11 Oct 16:33:42 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
11 Oct 16:33:42 - [nodemon] starting `node test.js`
testing!
11 Oct 16:33:42 - [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Then I change the file in some way. I change what gets printed or whatever. Nodemon just sits there. It doesn't re-run the script or do anything.

What am I missing here? It seems like a completely simplified example of how nodemon should work but it just isn't doing anything after the initial start... Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

Comment: Which version of Express are you using? Have you tried just running `nodemon` with no arguments?

Comment: I just tried (same version) and it works fine. Maybe a stupid question but are you sure your file is actually saved on the disk? I had a rare bug with Visual Studio Code where the software showed me my file was saved and all but when I checked with another editor, the changes were'nt there; I lost few minutes like that.

Comment: File is definitely saved. @Roope what does Express have to do with it? I'm not using Express... Can't you use nodemon without Express?

Comment: @Roope `nodemon` w/o any arguments just gives me the `Usage: nodemon [nodemon options] [script.js] [args]`.

Comment: @JakeWilson Right, my bad. Naturally you don't need to use Express. I made a subconscious assumption, this often happens with Express 4. Anyway, you could try running it with the `-L` flag.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure running

```
node test.js
```

doesnt exit the script the same way.

If the script exit, nodemon exit too.

Comment: No, `nodemon` will watch the file anyway and restart the script when change is detected. I just tried with some `console.log` and the script is rerun on change as expected.